# Django Password Reset

Tags: python, django, contraseña

Recien estoy aprendiendo django y estoy implementado el recuperacion de contraseña por medio de un email. Pero al correr el proyecto no me muestra mis templates, me muestra las de django, ni me envia el correo, ya intente con el puerto 587, ademas active la opcion de seguridad en la cuenta gmail que estoy utilizando y aun asi no funciona.

**Actualizacion:** Solucione lo de las plantillas pero ahora tengo este problema y es que en mi template para ingresar mi correo para el envio del enlace de recuperacion me da este error (adjunto captura de mis url y del template)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

espero que este disfrutando todo lo que te puede ofrecer Django. Creo que el problema es el siguiente, en tu error te dice:

> NoReverseMatch ar /reset/password_reset

Este error nos dice que la url no hace match con ninguna de tus urls, y por lo que veo estas combinando url() y path(). Debes de usar solo path() para las urls ya que url() se esta dejando atras.

Lo primero que sugiero es que cambies esas url por path a ver si con esto ya te da el match:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [

path('password/reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
                                              html_email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html'),
         name='password_reset'),
path('password/reset/hecho/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html'),

     name='password_reset_done'),
path('password/reset/confirmar/<uidb64>/<token>/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html'),
     name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('password/reset/completo/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html'),
     name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

con estos paths deberia de cargarte correctamente, para entrar es con la url: 127.0.0.1:8000/password/reset/